# Using Masked Custom Domain with no iframe on IBM Bluemix

Tags: dns, server, redirect, ibm-cloud

I have a domain with Namecheap that I would like to point to my IBM Bluemix app. I have tried masked redirection: this just places the Bluemix app in an iframe. The issue with that is that when the user clicks a link in the app, the URL in the bar doesn't change (only the iframe path changes). Additionally, if I use unmasked redirection, then the URL simply changes to the Bluemix URL (appname.mybluemix.net). What can I do? Is it possible to point my domain to Bluemix's name-servers? How can I get my app to behave like it resides at the domain (No iframe, and no URL change). Is this even possible with Bluemix?

Thank you,

--

Comment: You need to use a so-called customer domain, see here https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/updatingapps.html It requires configuration of both Bluemix and your domain with your provider.

Comment: @data_henrik I only see how to setup the Bluemix route (not from Namecheap). How do I go about actually setting this up? Thank you!

Comment: Every registrar has its own configuration menu. You need to change the DNS settings and point the domain or a subdomain to Bluemix. Personally, I used a CNAME entry with my registrar http://blog.4loeser.net/2014/07/using-custom-domain-for-my-bluemix.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't it with Namecheap (Url cloacking) and URL Frame is bad for SEO.

You can use a **custom domain** for your Bluemix Application. The documentation is here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/updatingapps.html and here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/securingapps.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Those links only seem to describe how to create the route on the Bluemix side, they don't seem to say what steps are actually necessary to set this up on the domain-side. How would I go about actually setting this up?

Comment: set the custom domain as a  'A' type in your own DNS configuration.

Comment: Thanks again! In the Namecheap "A Record" type DNS configuration, it asks for an "IP Address" and won't except my Bluemix URL (myapp.bluemix.net). I'm not sure what to enter there since the Bluemix app IP address changes every time the app is re-staged. What can I do?

Comment: try nslookup or ping on your application host and you can see that the ip is the same after every restaging, cause this is the ip of the gateway. The gateway, then, re-address your request to your application. So, don't worry about this. Simply follow the documentation and my information. If your app is on us-south\ng region you have to put: 75.126.81.68

Comment: Thanks again! Is this correct?

[Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/h8kZJsM.png).

I am getting a "400 Bad Request" right now. Do you know why this is?

Comment: this seems correct, but how did you configured bluemix side ?... Is your application on us-south ?

Comment: Thanks! I am on US-South, I also have the domain added as a domain and selected as a route for the app. What could be the issue?

Comment: Do I need to remove the myapp.mybluemix.net route?

Comment: no, It is not necessary that you remove the myapp.bluemix.net. Could you provide your domain ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97198/discussion-between-unknownuser-and-crescenzo-migliaccio).